# Javascript: change the colour of a radio button if it is checked and submitted

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to javascript and started to work on a quiz.
When the submit button is clicked I want the checked (false) radio button turns to i.e. "black"
I tried to read forums however i have not found anything related to this issue.
My last try is the last line of the JS

Hope you can help me.
Here is my stuff ( i know it could be simpler ) :
the problematic part starts at line 51.
https://jsfiddle.net/av0txkco/

```js
function submitAnswers() {
  var total = 10;
  var score = 0;

  // Get User Input
  var q1 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q1"].value;
  var q2 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q2"].value;
  var q3 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q3"].value;
  var q4 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q4"].value;
  var q5 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q5"].value;
  var q6 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q6"].value;
  var q7 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q7"].value;
  var q8 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q8"].value;
  var q9 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q9"].value;
  var q10 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q10"].value;


  // Validation
  for (i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
    if (eval('q' + i) == null || eval('q' + i) == '') {
      alert('You missed question ' + i);
      return false;
    }
  }

  // Set Correct Answers
  var answers = ["a", "d", "b", "d", "a", "c", "a", "b", "b", "d"];

  // Check Answers
  for (i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
    if (eval('q' + i) == answers[i - 1]) {
      score++;
    }
  }

  // Display Results
  var summary = document.getElementById('results');
  results.innerHTML = '<h3>You scored <span>' + score + '</span> out of <span>' + total + '</span></h3>';

  q1submit4 = document.getElementById("q1green").style.background = "green";
  q2submit4 = document.getElementById("q2green").style.background = "green";
  q3submit4 = document.getElementById("q3green").style.background = "green";
  q4submit4 = document.getElementById("q4green").style.background = "green";
  q5submit4 = document.getElementById("q5green").style.background = "green";
  q6submit4 = document.getElementById("q6green").style.background = "green";
  q7submit4 = document.getElementById("q7green").style.background = "green";
  q8submit4 = document.getElementById("q8green").style.background = "green";
  q9submit4 = document.getElementById("q9green").style.background = "green";
  q10submit4 = document.getElementById("q10green").style.background = "green";

  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("q1red1").checked;
    document.getElementById("q1red1").style.background = "black";
  }



  // alert('You scored '+score+' out of ' +total);
  // radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked').style.background = "red"

  return false;
}
```

```css
body{
 background: white;
 color: black;
 font-family:'Arial', sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
}

#container{
 width:60%;
 background: white;
 margin:20px auto;
 overflow:auto;
 padding:25px;
}

header{
 text-align:center;
 border-bottom: black solid 1px;
}

header h1{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

header p{
 padding:0;
 margin-top:5px;
 color: black;
}

section{
 min-height:400px;
}

footer{
 text-align:center;
}

input[type='submit']{
 background: black;
 border:0;
 color: white;
 padding:10px 15px;
 cursor:pointer;
}

#results h3{
 background: white;
 padding:10px;
 margin:10px 0;
}

#results span{
 color: green;
 font-weight:bold;
}

/* RADIOBUTTON */


.radiobtn {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.radiobtn label {
  display: block;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* .radiobtn label:after, .radiobtn label:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 11px;
  top: 11px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: black;
} */
.radiobtn label:before {
  background: transparent;
  transition: 0.1s width cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1) 0s, 0.3s height cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 2) 0.1s;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 13px;
  background-position: center;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxNS4zIDEzLjIiPiAgPHBhdGggZmlsbD0iI2ZmZiIgZD0iTTE0LjcuOGwtLjQtLjRhMS43IDEuNyAwIDAgMC0yLjMuMUw1LjIgOC4yIDMgNi40YTEuNyAxLjcgMCAwIDAtMi4zLjFMLjQgN2ExLjcgMS43IDAgMCAwIC4xIDIuM2wzLjggMy41YTEuNyAxLjcgMCAwIDAgMi40LS4xTDE1IDMuMWExLjcgMS43IDAgMCAwLS4yLTIuM3oiIGRhdGEtbmFtZT0iUGZhZCA0Ii8+PC9zdmc+);
}
.radiobtn input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  appearance: none;
}
.radiobtn input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background: red;
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  border-color: black;
}
.radiobtn input[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
  background: grey;
}
.radiobtn input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Simple JavaScript Quiz</h1>
    <p>Test your knowledge in <strong>Math</strong></p>
  </header>
  <section>

    <form name="quizForm" onsubmit="return submitAnswers()">

      <h3>1. 1+1?</h3>
      <div class="radiobtn" id="good">
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a" />
        <label id="q1green" for="q1a">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b" />
        <label id="q1red1" for="q1b">3</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c" />
        <label for="q1c">4</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" id="q1d" />
        <label for="q1d">5</label>
      </div>

      <h3>2. 1+1</h3>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="a" id="q2a" />
        <label for="q2a">3</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="b" id="q2b" />
        <label for="q2b">4</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="c" id="q2c" />
        <label for="q2c">5</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="d" id="q2d" />
        <label id="q2green" for="q2d">2</label>
      </div>

      <h3>3. 1+1</h3>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q3" value="a" id="q3a" />
        <label for="q3a">1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q3" value="b" id="q3b" />
        <label id="q3green" for="q3b">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q3" value="c" id="q3c" />
        <label for="q3c">5</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q3" value="d" id="q3d" />
        <label for="q3d">6</label>
      </div>

      <h3>4. 1+1</h3>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q4" value="a" id="q4a" />
        <label for="q4a">1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q4" value="b" id="q4b" />
        <label for="q4b">12</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q4" value="c" id="q4c" />
        <label for="q4c">3</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q4" value="d" id="q4d" />
        <label id="q4green" for="q4d">2</label>
      </div>

      <h3>5. 1+1</h3>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q5" value="a" id="q5a" />
        <label id="q5green" for="q5a">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q5" value="b" id="q5b" />
        <label for="q5b">3</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q5" value="c" id="q5c" />
        <label for="q5c">5</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q5" value="d" id="q5d" />
        <label for="q5d">4</label>
      </div>

      <h3>6. 1+1</h3>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q6" value="a" id="q6a" />
        <label for="q6a">10</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q6" value="b" id="q6b" />
        <label for="q6b">6</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q6" value="c" id="q6c" />
        <label id="q6green" for="q6c">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q6" value="d" id="q6d" />
        <label for="q5d">1</label>
      </div>

      <h3>7. 1+1</h3>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q7" value="a" id="q7a" />
        <label id="q7green" for="q7a">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q7" value="b" id="q7b" />
        <label for="q7b">6</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q7" value="c" id="q7c" />
        <label for="q7c">12</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q7" value="d" id="q7d" />
        <label for="q7d">1</label>
      </div>

      <h3>8. 1+1</h3>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q8" value="a" id="q8a" />
        <label for="q8a">5</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q8" value="b" id="q8b" />
        <label id="q8green" for="q8b">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q8" value="c" id="q8c" />
        <label for="q8c">12</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q8" value="d" id="q8d" />
        <label for="q8d">1</label>
      </div>

      <h3>9. 1+1</h3>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q9" value="a" id="q9a" />
        <label for="q9a">5</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q9" value="b" id="q9b" />
        <label id="q9green" for="q9b">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q9" value="c" id="q9c" />
        <label for="q9c">12</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q9" value="d" id="q9d" />
        <label for="q9d">1</label>
      </div>

      <h3>10. 1+1</h3>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q10" value="a" id="q10a" />
        <label for="q10a">5</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q10" value="b" id="q10b" />
        <label for="q10b">22</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q10" value="c" id="q10c" />
        <label for="q10c">12</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q10" value="d" id="q10d" />
        <label id="q10green" for="q10d">2</label>
      </div>



      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit Answers">
    </form>
  </section>
  <div id="results"></div>
  <footer>
    <p>Heyho</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. DRY Don't Repeat Yourself. Use a loop. 2. You are not calling myFunction anywhere. 3 do not use eval. there is no need. 4 You can change the label background color but not the radio

Comment: Just btw: don't use `eval()` but rather an array where you can loop through. As for your question: A checkbox cannot have a background.

Comment: 3. `myFunction` it is not called and even if it were, it would only work for the first

Comment: Thank you for your help.  How can I colour the label with green the good answers like in the original after clicking on submit? It did not work: q1submit4 = document.getElementById("q1green").style.background = "green"; and how it is possible to colour the selected  wrong answers to "black" when hitting submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several issues.

1. DRY Don't Repeat Yourself. Use a loop.
2. You are not calling myFunction anywhere.
3. do not use eval. there is no need.
4. You can change the label background color but not the radio

If you want, you can hook up each rad with a click handler that will turn it red or green on click.

Please study the code below

```js
// Set Correct Answers
var answers = ["a", "d", "b", "d", "a", "c", "a", "b", "b", "d"];

function submitAnswers(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var score = 0;

  // Validation
  for (i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    var rad = document.querySelector("input[name=q" + (i + 1) + "]:checked");
    if (!rad || rad.length === 0) {
      alert('You missed question ' + (i + 1));
      return false;
    }
    var ok = rad.value === answers[i];
    score += ok ? 1 : 0;
    rad.nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = ok ? "green" : "red";
  }

  // Display Results
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = '<h3>You scored <span>' + score + '</span> out of <span>' + answers.length + '</span></h3>';

}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("quizForm").addEventListener("submit", submitAnswers);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#container {
  width: 60%;
  background: white;
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 25px;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: black solid 1px;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header p {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: black;
}

section {
  min-height: 400px;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type='submit'] {
  background: black;
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#results h3 {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#results span {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* RADIOBUTTON */

.radiobtn {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.radiobtn label {
  display: block;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* .radiobtn label:after, .radiobtn label:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 11px;
  top: 11px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: black;
} */

.radiobtn label:before {
  background: transparent;
  transition: 0.1s width cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1) 0s, 0.3s height cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 2) 0.1s;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 13px;
  background-position: center;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxNS4zIDEzLjIiPiAgPHBhdGggZmlsbD0iI2ZmZiIgZD0iTTE0LjcuOGwtLjQtLjRhMS43IDEuNyAwIDAgMC0yLjMuMUw1LjIgOC4yIDMgNi40YTEuNyAxLjcgMCAwIDAtMi4zLjFMLjQgN2ExLjcgMS43IDAgMCAwIC4xIDIuM2wzLjggMy41YTEuNyAxLjcgMCAwIDAgMi40LS4xTDE1IDMuMWExLjcgMS43IDAgMCAwLS4yLTIuM3oiIGRhdGEtbmFtZT0iUGZhZCA0Ii8+PC9zdmc+);
}

.radiobtn input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  appearance: none;
}

.radiobtn input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background: red;
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  border-color: black;
}

.radiobtn input[type="radio"]:checked+label:after {
  background: grey;
}

.radiobtn input[type="radio"]:checked+label:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Simple JavaScript Quiz</h1>
    <p>Test your knowledge in <strong>Math</strong></p>
  </header>
  <section>

    <form id="quizForm">

      <h3>1. 1+1?</h3>
      <div class="radiobtn" id="good">
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a" />
        <label id="q1green" for="q1a">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b" />
        <label id="q1red1" for="q1b">3</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c" />
        <label for="q1c">4</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" id="q1d" />
        <label for="q1d">5</label>
      </div>

      <h3>2. 1+1</h3>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="a" id="q2a" />
        <label for="q2a">3</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="b" id="q2b" />
        <label for="q2b">4</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="c" id="q2c" />
        <label for="q2c">5</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="d" id="q2d" />
        <label id="q2green" for="q2d">2</label>
      </div>

      <h3>3. 1+1</h3>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q3" value="a" id="q3a" />
        <label for="q3a">1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q3" value="b" id="q3b" />
        <label id="q3green" for="q3b">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q3" value="c" id="q3c" />
        <label for="q3c">5</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q3" value="d" id="q3d" />
        <label for="q3d">6</label>
      </div>

      <h3>4. 1+1</h3>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q4" value="a" id="q4a" />
        <label for="q4a">1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q4" value="b" id="q4b" />
        <label for="q4b">12</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q4" value="c" id="q4c" />
        <label for="q4c">3</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q4" value="d" id="q4d" />
        <label id="q4green" for="q4d">2</label>
      </div>

      <h3>5. 1+1</h3>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q5" value="a" id="q5a" />
        <label id="q5green" for="q5a">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q5" value="b" id="q5b" />
        <label for="q5b">3</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q5" value="c" id="q5c" />
        <label for="q5c">5</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q5" value="d" id="q5d" />
        <label for="q5d">4</label>
      </div>

      <h3>6. 1+1</h3>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q6" value="a" id="q6a" />
        <label for="q6a">10</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q6" value="b" id="q6b" />
        <label for="q6b">6</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q6" value="c" id="q6c" />
        <label id="q6green" for="q6c">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q6" value="d" id="q6d" />
        <label for="q5d">1</label>
      </div>

      <h3>7. 1+1</h3>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q7" value="a" id="q7a" />
        <label id="q7green" for="q7a">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q7" value="b" id="q7b" />
        <label for="q7b">6</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q7" value="c" id="q7c" />
        <label for="q7c">12</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q7" value="d" id="q7d" />
        <label for="q7d">1</label>
      </div>

      <h3>8. 1+1</h3>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q8" value="a" id="q8a" />
        <label for="q8a">5</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q8" value="b" id="q8b" />
        <label id="q8green" for="q8b">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q8" value="c" id="q8c" />
        <label for="q8c">12</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q8" value="d" id="q8d" />
        <label for="q8d">1</label>
      </div>

      <h3>9. 1+1</h3>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q9" value="a" id="q9a" />
        <label for="q9a">5</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q9" value="b" id="q9b" />
        <label id="q9green" for="q9b">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q9" value="c" id="q9c" />
        <label for="q9c">12</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q9" value="d" id="q9d" />
        <label for="q9d">1</label>
      </div>

      <h3>10. 1+1</h3>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q10" value="a" id="q10a" />
        <label for="q10a">5</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q10" value="b" id="q10b" />
        <label for="q10b">22</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q10" value="c" id="q10c" />
        <label for="q10c">12</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radiobtn">
        <input type="radio" name="q10" value="d" id="q10d" />
        <label id="q10green" for="q10d">2</label>
      </div>



      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit Answers">
    </form>
  </section>
  <div id="results"></div>
  <footer>
    <p>Heyho</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @mplungjan, Thank you for the code you provided.  How can I colour the label with green the good answers like in the original after clicking on submit? It did not work: q1submit4 = document.getElementById("q1green").style.background = "green"; and how it is possible to colour the selected  wrong answers to "black" when hitting submit.

Comment: The code to colour is in the script, I thought it was more useful to colour green when correct or red when wrong. Remove the `ok ?` and `: “red”` to get just green

Comment: It is awesome. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Regrettable, the looks of the radio button is dependent of the browser. 
There is a limit of what you can do.

However, there are ways around it.
For example, below, I am hiding the radio button (to keep the regular functionality); however, I am displaying some icons instead.

To make it easier to understand and go directly to the point, I am using jQuery and FontAwesome but you can use whatever you want instead.

```js
$(function() {

  $('input[type=radio].toggle').on("change", function () {
    $.each($('input[type=radio].toggle[name='.concat($(this).attr('name')).concat(']')), function () {  
      $('label[for=' + $(this).attr('id') + '] i.fa')
      .toggleClass('fa-toggle-on', this.checked)
      .toggleClass('fa-toggle-off', !this.checked)
      .toggleClass('black', this.checked)
      .toggleClass('blue', !this.checked);      
    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;   
}

span.toggle-icon {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; 
    font-weight: 900; 
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

span.toggle-icon.down::before {
  content: "\f0ab";
}
span.toggle-icon.up::before {
  content: "\f0aa";
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.black{
  color: black;
}

.muted {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-toggle success">
  <input type="radio" class="toggle"
         name="radio-toggle-group" id="radio-toggle-1"
         value="radio1" checked="">
  <label class="radio" for="radio-toggle-1">
    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-toggle-on"></i>
    <span class="text success">Option 1</span>
  </label>
</div> 
<div class="btn-toggle warning">
  <input type="radio" class="toggle" 
         name="radio-toggle-group" id="radio-toggle-2"                  
         value="radio2">
  <label class="radio" for="radio-toggle-2">
    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-toggle-off blue"></i>
    <span class="text warning">Option 2</span>
  </label>
</div> 
<div class="btn-toggle muted">
  <input type="radio" class="toggle"
         name="radio-toggle-group" id="radio-toggle-3"
         value="radio2" disabled="">
  <label class="radio" for="radio-toggle-3">
    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-toggle-off muted"></i>
    <span class="text muted">Option 3 (Disabled)</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the jQuery tag?

Comment: @mplungjan jQuery its a JavaScript  library, which simplifies the manipulation of DOMs for the coder, not a tag. The `$` sign is a shortcut for the word `jQuery` so `$('.className')` its the same as `jQuery('.className')`

Comment: Lol. I have coded JQ since v0.1 - the QUESTION is not “tagged” with jQuery and OP is not ready for jQuery - vanilla js is just fine here. See my answer